# mobile version of website doesn't fit horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, web

I'm trying to produce a mobile version of my website, but have encountered one problem:

The the whole website fits properly on the computer (with an example browser width of 480px) but leaves space on the right when viewing on my mobile phone (regardless of the browser I used). So the whole site looks good, but you can scroll "out of the website".

I first tried to disable horizontally scrolling, so I included this line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />
```

To disable the (still scrollable!) space on the right I added this to my "mobile.css":
It worked on the computer, but not on my mobile.

```
body{
width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

- My website is avaiable here: [my mobile website](http://minchc11.bplaced.net/test)
- My mobile.css file is located here: [my "mobile.css"](http://minchc11.bplaced.net/test)

I have tested the website on following mobile browsers:

- Google Chrome
- Dolphin
- The default android browser

I originally wanted to avoid Javascript, but if there is a javascript solution, please don't hesitate to post it!

Comment: Whatever solution you come up with, please don't disable scrolling, zooming or panning. These are usability features built into various platforms that are very useful, particularly for users with less than perfect eyesight.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning, I haven't thought about this so far. The only thing is that I'm not sure if there is a possible solution (just for the mobile version) without disabling horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I really dislike web pages that disable built–in functionality, hence the heads–up. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your layout to be mobile friendly, it's best to be thinking about this right from the beginning. So, for example, if you are going to set fixed widths on elements (which I don't recommend), such as—

```
#back-menu-left {with: 500px;}
```

you need to ask yourself what will happen to this on a small screen. So, either don't set that width, or immediately write an `@media` rule to override it on smaller screens.

(I didn't check through the rest of your code, just stopping when I found one oversized element. Best to check and see if there are any other overwide elements like that.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have read so many articles about disabling scrolling on mobile websites and the meta viewport that I totally forgot about @media screen! I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Adding @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) to my main css file (not the mobile one) did the trick for me.